# Creating a Public Javascript Website

Tags: html, css, web

I have written a javascript program with html and css that is fully functional. I want to make a public website with this program. What is the best way to do this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you provide more info about the code setup you have like what framework you have used? Is there any database involved or is it just a static website?

Comment: I have made a iron car with an engine and wheels that is fully functional. I want to make a trip through the Sahara desert. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have server configured. For sites having only javascript and html you need not require heavy servers like tomcat. You can look for any host provider to get some space/server.

Along with this you need to have domain name for your site. Go to any domain service provider like goDaddy and take a domain as you want.

After doing this your site can be accessible to everyone.

Comment: do you have any recommendations for where to find a server? Like a website?

Comment: there multiple options you can try out. godaddy is very good. otherwise open a account on AWS for free for year , buy domain name and host static site on AWS.(You need to put effort to understand AWS).